# How to change register value from a predefined array in powershell after testing the registry path?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to optimize IE11 for our application per user in case a GP is not allowed to be used. I want to optimize these settings with a single script so that it doesn't take me a lot of times each time i get the request.

I tried to create a powershell script that first tests the path of the registry key. 
After that it should provide a message to either cancel or continue and then it should change the values.

So far the "test-path" part works, but realy changing the values is not.

```
$RegPaths = 
'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation',
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap',
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1',
'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows'

#Test-path $RegPaths

$RegEdit = 
{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation' -name IntranetCompatibilityMode -value 0},
{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation' -name MSCompatibilityModegpupd -value 0},
{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap' -name AutoDetect -value 1},
{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' -name 1001 -value 0},
{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' -name 1004 -value 0},
{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' -name 1201 -value 0},
{Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows' -name PopupMgr -value 0}

#If (Test-path $RegPaths = True) 
#{write-host "Registry paths exist, continueing improving IE settings for ISCV client"}
#Foreach ($RegEdit) {if (Test-path $RegPaths -eq $True) {continue}}
#Else {write-host "Register path invalid or missing, canceling changes"}

If (( Test-Path $RegPaths) -eq $True) 
    {
        {write-host "Registry paths exist, continueing improving IE settings for ISCV client"}
        #{ForEach-object -process $RegEdit}
    Foreach ($RegEdit in $RegEdit)
        {start-job $RegEdit}
    }
Else
        {Write-Host " Path missing or invalid, cancel script"}
```

The -process, or the start-job is not changing the values from 0 to 1 for example, which is expected.

Thanks!

**Update**
Thanks for the advise so far. I was trying and noticed that only the "write-host" line and the first set-itemproperty line are actually working, after is nothing happening, any idea how or why?

```
{write-host "Registry paths exist, continueing improving IE settings for 
client"}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet 
Explorer\BrowserEmulation' -name IntranetCompatibilityMode -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet 
Explorer\BrowserEmulation' -name MSCompatibilityModegpupd -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap' 
-name AutoDetect -value 1}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' 
-name 1001 -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' 
-name 1004 -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' 
-name 1201 -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New 
Windows' -name PopupMgr -value 0}
```

**Update**  the above update is working, i didn't look good. Thanks!

Comment: (1.) You are using `Test-Path` to check an array of paths. That will return multiple `True` or `False`. Not good logic. (2.) `Foreach ($RegEdit in $RegEdit)` Both are `$RegEdit`. Consider using another variable. (3.) Except for your 3rd command, everything else is setting the value to 0. So if it works, the end result value would be 0.

Comment: Also, you don't need `Start-Job` - you can invoke the scripblocks synchronously with `&`

Comment: Thanks for the advise so far. I was trying and noticed that only the "write-host" line and the first set-itemproperty line are actually working, after is nothing happening, any idea how or why?

Comment: Thank you all, i guess i also did not see the correct value. so it was working .

Answer (score 0):

this code is working ok for me now:

```
{write-host "Registry paths exist, continueing improving IE settings for 
client"}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet 
Explorer\BrowserEmulation' -name IntranetCompatibilityMode -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet 
Explorer\BrowserEmulation' -name MSCompatibilityModegpupd -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap' 
-name AutoDetect -value 1}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' 
-name 1001 -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' 
-name 1004 -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -Path 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' 
-name 1201 -value 0}
    &{Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New 
Windows' -name PopupMgr -value 0}
```